# Add both text and variable in WordPress wp_nav_menu $menu_class

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, text, menu

I am generating a menu in WordPress using wp_nav_menu() function and I want to add both text and variable into the 'menu_class' property.

Now this is how I do it:

```
 `'menu_class'      => 'text' . $variable,`
```

However no class is shown when I use this method (no error/warnings as well).

I want to know how to add the text "text" and the variable "$variable" into 'menu_class' property?

Thanks

Comment: here's the [documentation for wp_nav_menu()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu).  It says for `menu_class`... the class that is applied to the ul element which encloses the menu items. Multiple classes can be separated with spaces. Formerly known as $wrap_class.

Comment: so maybe just add a space?  `text' . ' ' . $variable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's the documentation for [wp_nav_menu()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu). It says for menu_class...

> the class that is applied to the ul element which encloses the menu
>   items. Multiple classes can be separated with spaces. Formerly known
>   as $wrap_class

so try adding a space?

```
'menu_class'      => 'text' . ' ' . $variable,
```

or just

```
'menu_class'      => 'text ' . $variable,
```

this is apparenlty a good tutorial:  [IMPROVE YOUR WORDPRESS NAVIGATION MENU OUTPUT](http://www.kriesi.at/archives/improve-your-wordpress-navigation-menu-output)

---

This SO post deals with code that deals with two menu classes: [php code optimization for wordpress nav menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10789522/php-code-optimization-for-wordpress-nav-menu).  Are you sure that your variable has a value?  I work with PHP all the time and that's definitely how you do string concatenation.

Comment: Now, only the text and the space shows up, the variable disappeared.

Comment: what do you mean exactly?  where does it disappear?  I'm looking everywhere and it just always shows examples of separating the different class names with a space (which makes sense with CSS).

Comment: Both of the code does not work, the output is this: `class="text "`, there is only the text and the space, the variable is not there.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that I put the variable below wp_nav_menu(), now I moved it up and it worked.